# Symfony 3: Error message of embedded form with contraint on class property

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

If a class has a property of another class, validation can be cascaded by using the `Valid()` annotation, as shown in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html).

I've built an embedded form for that example and it correctly cascades errors when I put incorrect data into the form fields of the `Address` class.

However, if I leave all form fields of the class `Address` empty, no error is displayed. That seems to be ok. I need to specify `NotBlank()` or `NotNull` besides `Valid()` on the `address` property. Here is the complete example:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Address
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max = 5)
     */
    protected $zipCode;
}

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min = 4)
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $address;
}
```

With this code, leaving all fields of `address` empty makes the form submission invalid. This is what I want.

**But:** No error message is displayed on the form after submission. I think it has something to do with the fact that the error message for `NotNull()` is not associated to a single form field. How can I display the error?

Form type code:

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/AddressType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('street', TextType::class)
                ->add('zipCode', TextType::class)
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Address::class,
        ));
    }
}

// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/AuthorType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Author;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class)
                ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
                ->add('address', AddressType::class)
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Author::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

**Output of `dump($form->getErrors(true,true));`:**

```
AuthorController.php on line 33:
FormErrorIterator {#538 ▼
  -form: Form {#363 ▶}
  -errors: array:1 [▼
    0 => FormError {#748 ▼
      -message: "This value should not be null."
      #messageTemplate: "This value should not be null."
      #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
        "{{ value }}" => "null"
      ]
      #messagePluralization: null
      -cause: ConstraintViolation {#682 ▼
        -message: "This value should not be null."
        -messageTemplate: "This value should not be null."
        -parameters: array:1 [▶]
        -plural: null
        -root: Form {#363}
        -propertyPath: "data.author.address"
        -invalidValue: null
        -constraint: NotNull {#674 ▶}
        -code: "ad32d13f-c3d4-423b-909a-857b961eb720"
        -cause: null
      }
      -origin: Form {#489 ▶}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: show your form type please.

Comment: You probably need to set `add('address', AddressType::class, array( 'error_bubbling' => false)` in your `AddressType`. If you're using a custom twig form rendering you need to make sure that you have `{{ form_errors(address) }}` so that the error renders.

Comment: What do you get doing `dump($form->getErrors(true,true))` ?

Comment: @goto I appended the output of `dump` to my question. It shows, that the validation works. It seems to be just a matter of how to display the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you need to create an instance of the related object. This way the object is not null and you can  have its field validation

```
public function myAction() 
{
  $formObject = new Author();
  $formObject->setAddress(new Address())

  $this->createForm(AuthorType::class, $formObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set error_bubbling to false

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#error-bubbling

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'error_bubbling' => false
));
```

Comment: Tried that (at both possible locations: `AddressType` and `AuthorType`) but it has no effect.